# Arduino MP3/music and lights

Tags: arduino, mp3

I've had some experience programming/using an Arduino, and I thought of a fun personal project, but not sure where to start.

I'm wanting to build a project that can play music and control some adafruit/neopixel lights, basically I want to have a text file on an SD card with something like:

```
[SONG NAME]
file=song.mp3
00:00:00
Do something with the lights
00:00:30
Do something else
```

And my program will step through some pre-coded functions based on the current time in the song and what I have put in.

I know that is a very (very) crude representation of what it would be like

I know of the [Sparkfun MP3 player](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12660?_ga=1.153896316.596992971.1450392654) and the [Neopixel lights](https://www.adafruit.com/category/168).

Now my question is what would be the best way to achieve this? Should I buy an Arduino Mega or Due which will cover all the pinouts etc.?  or should I buy two smaller arduinos and have both communicate with each other to get the relevant information.

I'm not after code or anything, just Hardware advice, as I'm not sure if the Sparkfun would be right product as I need to be able to get the current time for the song that is playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could buy the arduino uno thats goes with the mp3 player shield shown in the hook up guide at:

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/mp3-player-shield-hookup-guide-v15?_ga=1.152578556.4384731.1419409974

As for the control sequence, you can use on of the hardware timer based interrupts available on the atmega328 processor to time the outputs while the file is being played.